# XOR always converging toward 0.5 using backpropagation in Sigmoidal neural net C++

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation

Thanks again for taking the time to read this post.

I know this question has been asked a lot , and i have checked many posts about this issue : however, my quest for a sucessfull XOR learning using backpropagation remain unfinished.

I tried, like suggested,  tweaking the learning rate, the momentum , with/out biases, etc, still no success.

Network consist of 2 input neuron, 2 hidden neurons, 1 output, **all** Sigmoids.
The output neuron seems to always converge around 0.5 for every inputs.

I am therefore requesting your precious skills for that matter.
I am using a self-made C++ library (so i can learn in deep how the basics work).

Here are lines-of-interest of my code :

**Get error derivative from output neuron**

```
void ClOutputSigmoidNeuron::ComputeErrorGradient()
{
    double wanted_output = this->m_dataset->GetNextData();
    double delta = wanted_output - this->m_result_buffer;
    this->m_error_gradient = delta * this->SigmoidDerivative(this->m_result_buffer);
}
```

**Get error derivative from hidden neuron**

```
void ClSigmoidNeuron::ComputeErrorGradient()
{
    double tmpBuffer = 0.00;
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<this->m_output_connections.size();i++)
    {
        ClNeuron* target_neuron = (ClNeuron*)m_output_connections[i]->m_target_neuron;
        tmpBuffer += (target_neuron->m_error_gradient * this->m_output_connections[i]->m_weight);
    }

    //Get the sigmoid derivative
    this->m_error_gradient = tmpBuffer * this->SigmoidDerivative(this->m_result_buffer);
}
```

**Weights update for a general neuron :**

```
void ClNeuron::UpdateWeights()
{ 
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<this->m_input_connections.size();i++)
    {
        double momentum = this->m_input_connections[i]->m_weight_last_delta * this->m_input_connections[i]->m_momentum_value;
        double new_weight_delta = this->m_learning_rate * this->m_error_gradient * this->m_input_connections[i]->m_data + momentum ;
        this->m_input_connections[i]->m_weight += new_weight_delta;
        this->m_input_connections[i]->m_weight_last_delta = new_weight_delta;
        this->m_input_connections[i]->m_number_of_time_updated++;
    }
}
```

**Transfer functions**

```
double ClNeuron::Sigmoid(double p_value)
{
    return 1.00 / (1.00 + std::exp(p_value*-1.00));
}


double ClNeuron::SigmoidDerivative(double p_value)
{
    double sigmoid = this->Sigmoid(p_value);
    return sigmoid * (1.00 - sigmoid);
}
```

**The function used to training**

```
bool ClBackPropagationSupervisedTrainer::Train()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->m_dataset_size; i++)
    {
        this->m_network->Fire();

        if (!this->m_network->ComputeErrorGradients())
        {
            std::cout << "ClBackPropagationSupervisedTrainer:Train - Oups" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        this->m_network->UpdateWeights();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Again, thanks for reading this, i know this question has been asked a lot !
Pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've been exploring this one for a while and just noticed this same problem in mine. When I use the hyperbolic tangent for my activation function it works well. It also works with leaky ReLU. But never quite learns it with ReLU. I'm still trying to figure out why some of these activation functions don't work in this trivial case.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, in case it can help someone, changing from a Sigmoid() network to a TanH() network solved the issue.

In some way it does make sense, and yet, a Sigmoid transfert function seems perfect for this kind of problem, since XOR is already normalized between 0 & 1...